# How to GET binary image correctly using redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, microsoft-graph-api, redux-observable

I am trying to GET image using redux-observable.

Based on [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get), it returns binary data of the requested photo.

I succeed getting the image using Postman (it shows the image in the result since it is binary).

However, when I try to use [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), **response** I got is always `null`, and **responseType** is always `json` no matter what I give for **Content-Type** like `image/jpeg`, `text/plain`, `application/json`.

```
export const getAvatarEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(GET_AVATAR)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax
        .get(
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value',
          {
            // 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myToken
          }
        )
        .do(res => console.log(res))  // <- the result
        .map(getAvatarSucceed)
        .catch(getAvatarFailed)
    );
```

Here is what I got. Maybe I should use something else instead of `ajax.get`?

```
{
  "originalEvent": {
    "isTrusted": true
  },
  "xhr": {},
  "request": {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": false,
    "withCredentials": false,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer hereIsMyToken",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "responseType": "json",
    "timeout": 0,
    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "responseType": "json",
  "response": null
}
```

Comment: do you need to provide an accept header w/ your binary image mime type? e.g. why is json the response type?

Comment: @Tim yeah, that is a good point. Based on the [api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get), I only need provide `Authorization`. However I actually did try adding `image/jpeg`, `text/plain`, `application/json` for **Content-Type**, but **responseType** is always `json`.

Comment: I believe 'Content-Type' here will only affect the request, not the response. You should be getting back a base64 encoded version of the image in body of the response. Can you add response body as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to first make sure it becomes clear that redux-observable and RxJS are separate things. This question is actually an RxJS question, as is nearly all questions you'll come across (even when using redux-observable) since redux-observable is small and really defers almost everything to idiomatic Rx. This is important because when asking questions if you present and phrase them as just Rx questions you'll find much more help and resources since it's a larger community overall. Hope this helps!

---

If you're using the built-in ajax utilities for RxJS v5, you'll need to use the regular `ajax()` helper, not the shorthand `ajax.get()` one.

Then you can provide `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to get the image as a binary data:

```
export const getAvatarEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(GET_AVATAR)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myToken
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
      .do(res => console.log(res))  // <- the result
      .map(getAvatarSucceed)
      .catch(getAvatarFailed)
    );
```

Since this question actually is unrelated to redux-observable, here's a working example demonstrating getting the binary data and then creating an `<img>` with it:

https://jsbin.com/mimijot/edit?js,output

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

ajax({
  url: 'https://proxy.apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/svc?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fv1.0%2Fme%2Fphoto%2F%24value',
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer {token:https://graph.microsoft.com/}' },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    const buffer = res.response;
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  });
```

Comment: Worked for me, changing it to plain `ajax()` call instead of àjax.post()` and adding `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` helped

Answer (score 1):

When building the Graph explorer with Angular 4, I encountered the same issue.  In our case, when requesting images we have to set the `responseType` parameter to `ArrayBuffer` instead of the default value.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/blob/master/src/app/graph-service.ts#L54

```
case "GET": // for all JSON requests to Graph
        return this.http.get(query, {headers: requestHeaders}).toPromise();
case "GET_BINARY": // when fetching images
        return this.http.get(query, {responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer, headers : requestHeaders}).toPromise();
```

And then when processing the response, we get the blob URL and set the image element's src:

```
 let blob = new Blob( [ result.arrayBuffer() ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
 let imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );

 const imageResultViewer = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById("responseImg");
 imageResultViewer.src = imageUrl;
```

It looks like `Rx.DOM.ajax` has the responseType property, so I recommend changing that but I'm not an RxJS expert!  More info about `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` can be found at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Final code:

```
export const getAvatarEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$
.ofType(GET_AVATAR)
.mergeMap(action =>
  aja:@{
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
      // 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + store.getState().auth.token
    }
  })
    .map(getAvatarSucceed)
    .catch(getAvatarFailed)
);
```